# CUDA conflict with Wine

Tags: nvidia, wine, cuda, blender

Every time I install Wine on Ubuntu 14.04 my CUDA gets disabled, so I can't use GPU compute with Cycles in Blender. For some reason I can either use Wine or CUDA, not both. I forgot to mention that even the OpenCL (Open Computing Language) driver gets disabled.

I have tried both of the NVIDIA CUDA toolkits, from the Ubuntu Software Center and the CUDA 6.5 toolkit from the Nvidia website. Unfortunately I get the same problem. I have three GPUs - 2 GTX 760s and one GTX 560 Ti. The moment I install Wine, Blender stops detecting them under the Compute Device. I have tried the nvidia-331 graphics driver and also nvidia-340 from the website. I don't know what else to do.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: This is an easy command to install Nvidia graphics driver, CUDA and Wine in Ubuntu 14.04: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 libcudart5.5 nvidia-cuda-toolkit wine`. Is that what you did or did you install some different packages? Please add the package names of the Nvidia graphics driver, CUDA and Wine packages you installed to your question.

Comment: No that's the one.I even installed the cuda toolkit from nvidia's site.For some reason I can either use wine or cuda not both.I forgot to mention that even even the OpenCL driver gets disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had that error and I fixed it by installing Wine Staging.To do so add the official Wine Staging PPA by typing this into the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
```

After that do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine-staging
```

Install this in case you want to use Wine Staging system wide which I recommend, although in case your want to install PlayOnLinux :

```
sudo apt-get install wine-staging-compat
```

Then go to the site and follow the instructions for trusty version as the one included in the repositories is an old version of Play On Linux.